# Generate Fillable PDF from word

Tags: ms-word, pdf-generation, itext

I have a word template with some empty fields, around *25 templates*. I need to generate **fillable PDF** of those templates programmatically.

Specifically *how can I define fields (textbox, checkbox) in my word template* to generate PDF.

I have worked on **itextsharp** but it allows me to generate Fillable PDF from a PDF itself, and I didn't find any way to edit it.

Comment: *iTextSharp... I didn't find any way to edit it.* - What do you mean, did you want to edit the form elements or other page content?

Comment: Just for clarification, iText knows absolutely nothing about Microsoft Word. So are you asking for something to do in MS Word so that when you save it (via MS Word) to PDF you will have form fields that you can set via iText? If so, this is 100% something that you need to handle in Word, iText won't be able to help you. According to this post it is not possible: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-word/create-word-2010-form-and-convert-it-to-a-pdf-with/a6739dc7-e973-4ea4-882e-d0bdfa2217db

Comment: @mkl - If i create fillable fields using itextsharp, how can I edit text and other images with formatting from my template.

One template is around 8 pages with 4 textbox and 3 checkbox fields.

Comment: I don't get your use case. Do you want to edit the regular (fixed) page contents in a PDF? Or form contents? Or some Word template?

Comment: I have word template, and I want to convert it into a fillable PDF (with textbox & checkbox)

Comment: So you have some objects Word considers form elements and you hope for an export Word-to-PDF to transform those objects into PDF form fields? Or would it suffice to take the export from word as form background and separately define form fields on it using some PDF library, e.g. iText / iTextSharp?